# How to get true color from RGB

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a camera whose output is in RGB.
What is the preferred way to translate RGB values into "Green" (e.g.) or any other color?
Not talking about 0,255,0 of course but more subtle values

Comment: Set up  a 3D array of RGB values on an equally-spaced grid.  Each incoming RGB triple would be mapped to the _nearest_ known color.

Comment: You should include the language you are using, assuming you want help with implementation.

Comment: I an writing this with C++ on Windows. I don't quite get your idea.  Say I get (12,13,14), which is of course a variation of black, and I want it interpreted as black, What value would be in the matrix?

Comment: You would map each RGB value to the nearest point with a human readable color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign colors depending on how humans classifies them then you need to leave **RGB** space and move for example to **HSL** or **HSV**.

When in [those spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) **H** (hue) is what humans normally mean with "color" (like "green").

A simple way to get H is to subtract the minimum of R, G and B from all three and scale the maximum of what remains to 1. Then you have 6 cases (6 "slices" of the color wheel) depending on which component got to 0, which to 1 and which is the intermediate one. In Python

```
def H(r, g, b):
    # Remove min (this maximizes saturation)
    minv = min(r, g, b)
    r -= minv
    g -= minv
    b -= minv

    # Scale max to 1 (this normalizes brightness)
    maxv = max(r, g, b)
    if maxv == 0:
        return None # H for pure black is undefined

    k = 60.0 / maxv
    r = int(r * k + 0.5)
    g = int(g * k + 0.5)
    b = int(b * k + 0.5)

    # Compute result
    if r == 60:
        return (g - b) % 360
    elif g == 60:
        return 120 + b - r
    else:
        return 240 + r - g
```

Comment: thanks, will look into that. Do you know of a standard conversion library or function?

Comment: try the [colour package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colour), easily found by searching for _python color package_

Comment: I disagree. only hue won't help you at all. you throw a way valuable information if you just use hue.

Comment: @Piglet: hue is what humans mean when they say just "green". "Pale green" or "Grayish green" or "Dark green" would add more information, but green red or purple is hue. If you want to classify green cars images then you need to look at hue value.

Comment: @6502 he asked for "any other colour" and more subtle values than 0 255 0. I see no reason to implement something limited to basic colours if you can have pretty much any colour with the same effort. you still need to map Hue values to colour names anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 1D algorithm which you can consider.  Start by deciding how many color names you want to have over the domain.  For example, if we were just looking at red, you might have four colors:

```
[bright red, red, burgundy, black]
```

These colors would occur at the following red values:

```
[255, 170, 85, 0]
```

Now, when your program encounters a point with a random red value, you can choose the color name which most closely matches it.  For example, the red value 200 is closest to 170, which is red, so you would report the color as being red.

This approach can be extended to the three dimensions of RGB with a little work.

Comment: Thanks tim, but I have RGB, so red value itself is meaningless.  If all 3 values are 255, or 170, or 85 then its gray, not red,  So again, how to transform the 3 values of RGB into human color that makes sense?

Comment: I said that you would need to extend to 3 dimensions.  So you would find the _nearest_ point in RGB space which you have mapped to a color name.

Comment: Find the closest mapped value for red, green, and blue and then grab that color name.

Comment: This will work, except that you should calculate the color differences in Lab color space so that they match human perceptual differences.

Comment: @Bull thanks for the comment, and I guess that what you are saying is that in practice the grid might not be divided up evenly, but rather would be divided based on human perception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the RGB values to colour names using some sort of list.

I suggest you get something like that into your software:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F

Then use the RGB values you have to get the best match from that table.

Please note the importance of illumination and white balance. Precise colour recognition is very difficult to achieve.